# Using gsub in certain paragraphs of the text

Tags: ruby

I need to make a very simple string replace,emt, but only in certain parts of the file. I plan to use `gsub`, but I can't make it work to exclude the rest of the text. For instance, let's try to replace the word `text`:

```
    <String source= this text file is a test'> This is a text instance that I do want to remove</String>
```

The 'text' instance that is inside the tag structure  should remained unchanged. The second instance of 'text' is the one I'm concerned of.

My code is very simple, so far:

```
    string = File.read(file)    
    replace = string.gsub(/text/, "whatever")
```

Expected result would be:

```
    <String source= this text file is a test'> This is a whatever instance that I do want to remove</String>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = File.read(file)

splited_strings = string.split(/(?=[<>])/)
splited_strings.each do |substring|
    # means it's out of tag
    if substring.include?(">")
        substring.gsub!(/text/, "whatever")
    end
end

new_str = splited_strings.join("")
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó perfectamente. Entiendo que el argumento de ```split``` es una ```regexp```. ¿Podrías más o menos explicarme como funciona en este caso?

Comment: @Topa_14 The regexp splits string by < or >
Usually splited strings does not include spliters.
I've added spliters to splited strings by adding ?= to regexp

Answer (score 4):

```
str = "<String text source> This is a text instance I want to remove</String>"
```

```
r = /\btext\b(?![^<>]*>)/
```

```
str.gsub(r, '')
  "<String text source> This is a  instance I want to remove</String>"
```

```
str1 = "The <best text can> precede text that is good <or text that is bad> or indifferent text."<!-->
str1.gsub(r, '')
  #=> "The <best text can> precede  that is good <or text that is bad> or indifferent ."
```

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing* regex definition mode to make it self-documenting.

```
/
\btext\b  # match 'text' with word breaks fore and aft
(?!       # begin a negative lookahead
  [^<>]*  # match zero or more character other than '<' and '>'
  >       # match '>'
)         # end negative lookahead
/x        # free-spacing regex definition mode.
```

---

Another way is to use the regular expression

```
/(?:\A|>)[^<>]*\K\btext\b/
```

which in free-spacing regex definition mode is written as follows.

```
/
(?:       # begin a non-capture group
  \A|>    # match the beginning of the string or '<'
)         # end non-capture group
[^<>]*    # match zero or more character other than '<' and '>'
\K        # discard previous matches and reset start of match to
          # current location
\btext\b  # match 'text' with word breaks fore and aft
/x        # free-spacing regex definition mode.
```

Comment: Second example 1) missing closing double quote. 2) Input or Output is incorrect. Output based on Input: `"The <best text can> precede text that is good >or  that is bad <or indifferent text>."` or Input based on Output: `"The <best text can> precede text that is good <or text that is bad> or indifferent text."`

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks, I cut and pasted the incorrect `str`. I see Chester is near Φιλαδέλφεια. You work in the latter?

Comment: I abhor cities, too many people for me. I work in the burbs NW of where the mutinous and revolutionary actions of insurgents spawned this [adjective of your choosing] country I call home.